# How do I navigate from signout to signin screen using createSwitchNavigator in my case?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

```
const RootNav = createStackNavigator(
  {

    Splash: {
        screen:Splash
    },
    BeforeLogin: {
        screen:BeforeLogin
    },    
    Signin: {
        screen:Signin
    },
    Tabs: {
        screen:TabHolder
    },
    ForgotPassword: {
        screen:ForgotPassword
    },
    Signup: {
        screen:Signup
    },

  },
  {
      headerMode:'none',
      mode:'modal', 
  }
);

export default class Index extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <RootNav />
    );
  }
}
```

Index is the main class which gets called initially.

```
// Below is the TabHolder Screen which is created in RootNav

import { createBottomTabNavigator, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const ProfileMainTab = createStackNavigator({

      Profile: {
          screen:Profile
      },
      EditProfile: {
          screen:EditProfile
      },
      FollowersList: {
          screen:FollowersList
      },
      Following: {
        screen:Following
      },
      FollowersRequest: { 
          screen:FollowersRequest
      },
      Settings: {
          screen:Settings
      },
      Settings2: {
          screen:Settings2
      },
      Payment: {
          screen:Payment
      },
      CreditCard: {
          screen:CreditCard
      },
      VisaCard: {
        screen:VisaCard
      },
      Messaging: {
          screen:Messaging
      },
      TopRanking: {
        screen:TopRanking
      },
      WorldTopRank: {
          screen:WorldTopRank
      },
  },
  {
      headerMode:'none',
      mode:'modal'
  }
);

const HomeMainTab = createStackNavigator({
     Home: {
       screen: Home,
     },
     SharePicture: {
       screen: SharePicture,
     },
     OtherProfile: {
       screen: OtherProfile,
     },
    },
     {
      headerMode:'none',
      mode:'modal'
     }
);

const TabNav = createBottomTabNavigator ({

  HomeMainTab: {
      screen: HomeMainTab,
      navigationOptions: {    }
    },
    Search: {
      screen: Search,
      navigationOptions: {    }
    },
    AddPost: {
      screen: AddPost,
      navigationOptions: {    }
    },
    FollowersList: {
      screen: FollowersList,
      navigationOptions: {    }
    },
    ProfileMainTab: {
      screen: ProfileMainTab,
      navigationOptions: {    }    
  },{
      tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
      animationEnabled: true,
      swipeEnabled: true, 
  }
);

export default class TabHolder extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (<TabNav/>)
  }
}
```

I have a signout button in my Settings Screen. So now when I click on Signout, I want to navigate back to Signin Screen. But I'm not able to navigate back.
How can I solve my issue by using **createSwitchNavigator**? Please help. 
I'm also not able to navigate using **this.props.navigation.navigate('Signin');** from signout button.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with navigation Props.

why do you need to do this?

```
export default class TabHolder extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (<TabNav/>)
  }
}
```

it create a react native component where a navigation require a navigation object

so please try to `export default TabNav`

Comment: Jigar I did what you said. But now I'm not able to navigate from Sign in to Home Screen after I changed my navigation to createSwitchNavigator.

Comment: Hey, I solved it. I'll post the answer soon. Thank you :)